# Cleaning up location.pathname to load files and select elements with href attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a script where essentially I'm trying to find the location of a .php file using javascript/jquery (with `location.pathname`). So, my problem is basically that if the user inputs something weird like:

`url.com/` or `url.com////` or `url.com////index.php////` or `url.com////index.php.////`, then I need a way of dealing with this so I can obtain `/index.php` so I can select that file and load some content from it (using ajax), as well as selecting an element that has `href = "/index.php"` so I can make it an active link.

There's also the additional problem of something like this:

`url.com/projects/index.php`, `url.com////projects//index.php` for which I'd like to have an output of `/projects/index.php` to properly select the file once again.

Is there a standard way for doing this? I'd like to avoid using some regex or string replace method because I'm not sure if it will be able to handle all cases, although if the proper way to go about his is to do that then I'll go ahead and implement it. The browser uses a parser to determine what file to load, so if there's a solution that uses something similar (maybe built in or something) then that would be great. I tried searching for jquery url parsers or cleanups but I'm actually not sure what the term is that I should be looking for so my searches came up short.

**EDIT**: Just as some background, I'm implementing this basically: http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/, but I need a way to tweak it so it can find files in sub directories as well.

**EDIT2:** Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

**EDIT3:** Here's the ajax call I'm using, which fires on popstate:

```
var file = location.pathname;
$("#content").load(file + " #content", function() {
    $("#menu ul a").removeClass("current");
    $("#menu ul a[href="+file+"]").addClass("current");
});
```

When I do this for weird browser entries, the load and href fail obviously, since the `href` attribute is set to `href = "/index.php"` in my website. The `load` function also fails for weird inputs, even though the page can be loaded.

Comment: Why is the user entering all those extra slashes?

Comment: @Barmar most likely the user won't, but in the case he/she does I still want my website to perform properly

Comment: I just put www.domain.com/////index.php in my browser, and it worked without rewriting. I suspect the webserver deals with it, so you don't need to.

Comment: Why would the ajax call be different? Can’t you just request `"/////index.php"` if that is what the user wants?

Comment: @David I added more info to the question.

Comment: @Barmar My situation is that I have to determine which file is being loaded and it's location from the url in javascript (which I don't like, but it seems to be the simplest option). The above weird inputs still work, so I need a way to find out the file location even with weird inputs. Take a look at my edits if to see what I mean. I'm trying to build a website off the idea from css-tricks.com but I'd like it to be robust. If this is the wrong way to approach this then I'm open to any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Replace multiple forward slashes with a single forward slash, then remove the domain name if necessary.  Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var userStr = 'url.com////projects//index.php';
    userStr = userStr.replace(/\/{2,}/g, '/').replace(/url.com/, '');
    // userStr = /projects/index.php
});
```

This obviously won't work for every combination of URL that your user might provide, but then I doubt you'll find a regular expression that handles every possibility either.  If a user sends you "url.com////index.php.////" then give them a 404 in return.

Comment: Yea I figured this might be the route I have to go. I don't get it though, if the browser is able to parse the url and find the file, then why can't javascript do the same thing?